# I interviewed at a company that offered to reimburse my expenses but after the interview they don't answer my emails anymore, what should I do?

Tags: interviewing, human-resources, reimbursement

I was invited by a company for an on-site interview. Before I could even ask about it, I was told (in writing) by the HR person inviting me (let's call him David) that my accommodation expenses will be reimbursed and that I will be given some fixed amount of money to cover all the other expenses (eg: travelling, food).

I went to the interview and after a few days I received an automatic mail from a service email account telling me I was not successful. I wrote to David (my only point of contact with the company) to get information about the reimbursement but I received no answer. A few days later I received another email by him telling me again I was not successful. This email was not "tailor-made" to me, but just a standard template. I tried again asking him about the reimbursement and again I received no answer.

Two weeks has passed now since I tried to contact David the first time.

The company is quite big (>10k employee) and I don't think there is any attempt here to save money by not paying me. My suspect is just that David is a little bit careless or busy elsewhere and my personal case is just slipping through the cracks.

I am considering writing again to David, or looking for the email address of this boss/general HR and writing them. Is there anything else that I can do? Should I raise my voice or consider this kind of things "normal" and just wait for a peaceful ending?

Comment: Do you have anything in writing/email that backs this up?

Comment: @Snow: Yes, of course.

Comment: @heapOverflow Its not obvious by the wording of your question that you have a clear commitment from the company that they would reimburse you for your travel expenses.

Comment: Go right ahead and contact someone else in the company, like HR, and also cc "David".

Comment: It is a HUGE mistake to "be the bank" for a company.  In any situation like this, let them buy the ticket/hotel for you.

Comment: @Fattie: This is a possibility, but at the moment I don't have any other address of HR and I don't know who is the boss of David. This requires me to do some investigation.

Comment: sorry to hear it @heapOverflow.  It's annoying but you may have to simply telephone them and ask for HR, or similar.  Bummer.

Comment: How much money are we talking about ? Despite being right, it's going to take some non-trivial amount of time &  effort to get this resolved. Is it worth it?

Comment: @Hilmar: A few hundred euros. But it is really a matter of principle.

Answer (score 12):

Escalate to the company HR, this is Davids job, not an accidental oversight, all sorts of dodgy things may be happening, but all you should care about is getting reimbursed if it's a considerable sum you don't want to write off to experience.

Don't assume they're not trying to save money, the size of the company is immaterial. Ignoring someone owed money is a time honored tactic in the hope they just go away.

Since all your communication is via email, use your records when speaking to HR and move forwards or give up after you get an actual reply and review your options.

Answer (score 5):

These days, you are really empowered through social media.  These big companies go to great expense to keep their name clean.  If all other avenues fail for you, I suggest you post your concern to the companies Twitter page.  You'll for sure attract some attention to your cause and hopefully will get some followup.

Comment: This is an *excellent idea*.  The only thing I would add is do not embellish.  Tell the **truth** and be able to back up what you claim.

Comment: I doubt that I would do this first; only as a last resort. remember, that tweet stays visible, and the next company that you apply to might scan your tweets as part of the application process

Answer (score 4):

If you are owed money, it is not HR you need to deal with, but Accounts.

Send a demand for payment addressed to their Accounts Payable department, and including the relevant information such as the dates, the amounts, copies of receipts and a copy of the promise to reimburse you.

This is a legally required step before you can sue for payment, and serves as official notice that payment is required. Taking this step shows you are serious.

Exactly how to do this may differ in your jurisdiction, but it is not difficult. For example, in the UK:

- https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/demand-immediate-payment-of-a-debt-form-sd2

Once this is received, they may choose to either pay, or dispute the payment, or offer a different amount, but you will have the attention of the right people. If they neither pay, nor dispute the payment, the next step is small claims court.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything else that I can do?

Since you have some proof in writing, you *may* be able to sue the company.  I am not sure **the cost of a lawyer** and the headache would be worth getting your expenses reimbursed.

Do not just **show up** at the company door demanding payment and creating an scene.  This *could* lead to you being arrested.  Writing a review *may* make you feel better and save others the pain your going through.

Your **best** bet is to **learn** from this.  Going forward if travel is involved, have *the company* pay for the expenses so you don't have to worry about reimbursement during the interview phase.